# tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy implementation with sessions not with Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, distributed-system

I want to deploy the deep model on multiple GPUs. I search google and found that I can use `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()`.TensorFlow introduces MirroredStrategy to train the model on multiple parallel GPUs. The link is available here [Distributed training with Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/keras) for your reference. I am also following one blog, but that is also in Keras. [Train a Neural Network on multi-GPU with TensorFlow](https://towardsdatascience.com/train-a-neural-network-on-multi-gpu-with-tensorflow-42fa5f51b8af).
All the helping material regarding this library is available for the support of Keras. I do not want to use Keras for my program.
For Use case, I am mentioning some code of lines:

```
# Train CNN
print("Training CNN... ")

max_accuracy = 0.0

for i in range(num_training_iterations):

idx_train = np.random.randint(0, train_size, batch_size)

xt = np.reshape(data_train[idx_train], [batch_size, segment_size * num_input_channels])

yt = np.reshape(labels_train[idx_train], [batch_size, n_classes])
ft = np.reshape(features[idx_train], [batch_size, num_features])

sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: xt, y_: yt, h_feat: ft, keep_prob: dropout_rate})

if i % eval_iter == 0:   # After every 1000 iterations it check test data on the model => Moreover in first iteration it try test on the model which is trained just on 200 samples data

    train_accuracy, train_entropy, y_pred = sess.run([accuracy, cross_entropy, y_conv],
    feed_dict={ x : data_test, y_: labels_test, h_feat: features_test, keep_prob: 1}) #in testing no dropout so keep_prob=1

    print("step %d, entropy %g" % (i, train_entropy))
    print("step %d, max accuracy %g, accuracy %g" % (i, max_accuracy, train_accuracy))
    print(classification_report(labels_test_unary, np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1), digits=4))

    if max_accuracy < train_accuracy:
        max_accuracy = train_accuracy
```

How can I use tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy() without Keras libraries in case of above give code?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. This is just a demo of combination of `Session` and `Strategy`

```py
import logging
import tensorflow as tf

FORMAT = '%(asctime)s, %(levelname)-4s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, level=logging.INFO)
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
# tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

# Create a MirroredStrategy
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

global_batch_size = 4

# Define your model, optimizer, and loss function
def build_model(dist_inputs: tf.distribute.DistributedValues, optimizer):
  logging.info("dist_inputs:%s", dist_inputs)
  def replica_fn(inputs):
    logging.info("inputs:%s", inputs)

    features = inputs["features"]
    labels = inputs["labels"]
    weight = tf.compat.v1.get_variable("W", shape=(32, 1))
    bias = tf.compat.v1.get_variable("b", shape=(1,1))
    logits = tf.matmul(features, weight) + bias
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        labels, logits)) / global_batch_size
    grad_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss, tf.compat.v1.global_variables())
    train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grad_and_vars)
    with tf.control_dependencies([train_op]):
      return tf.identity(loss)
  per_replica_loss = strategy.run(replica_fn, args=(dist_inputs,))
  mean_loss = strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.SUM,
                              per_replica_loss,
                              axis=None)
  return mean_loss


# Load and preprocess your dataset
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
  features = tf.random.normal((4, 32), name="features")
  labels = tf.cast(
      tf.random.uniform((4, 1), minval=0, maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32), tf.float32)

def data_fn(ctx: tf.distribute.ReplicaContext):
  logging.info("my replica_id:%s", ctx.replica_id_in_sync_group)
  logging.info("features.device:%s", features.device)
  return {"features": features, "labels": labels}

# Distribute the data
dist_inputs = strategy.experimental_distribute_values_from_function(
    data_fn)
logging.info("dist_inputs:%s", dist_inputs)

with graph.as_default():
  with strategy.scope():
    logging.info("num_replicas_in_sync:%d", strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)
    opt = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer()
    loss = build_model(dist_inputs, opt)
    var_init = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()

with graph.as_default():
  logging.error("init_op:%s, mean_loss:%s", var_init, loss)
  with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(var_init)
    for _ in range(3):
      print(sess.run(loss))
```